# Mock static method call using @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito, powermockrunner

I'm using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`. i need to mock a static method call, `MosConfigFactory.getInstance()`. I can't use  `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`. how can i mock a static method call using MockitoJUnitRunner?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mockito inline

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Sample code :

```
assertEquals("foo", Foo.method());
 try (MockedStatic mocked = mockStatic(Foo.class)) {
    mocked.when(Foo::method).thenReturn("bar");
    assertEquals("bar", Foo.method());
    mocked.verify(Foo::method);
 }
 assertEquals("foo", Foo.method());
```

More information setup [on Ofiicial Documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks)

Also this is turned off by default and as per offical documentation [you need to turn it on](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.1.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#Mocking_Final):

> This mock maker is turned off by default because it is based on
> completely different mocking mechanism that requires more feedback
> from the community. It can be activated explicitly by the mockito
> extension mechanism, just create in the classpath a file
> /mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker containing the value
> mock-maker-inline.